# How to refresh Datatable data from js array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using the jquery DataTables plugin to display an array of objects.  I would like to clear the table and redraw using the changed data.  However, the only way I've been able to do that so far is to destroy the table and reinitialize.  I'd like to know if there is a simple way to refresh from JS data source.  This is what I'm doing, it works but feels wrong...

```
if (NAMESPACE.table){
  NAMESPACE.table.destroy();
}

NAMESPACE.table = $('#assets-table').DataTable({
  "data": filteredData,
  "columns": [
      { "data": "id" },
      { "data": "type" },
      { "data": "city" },
      { "data": "state"}
  ]
 });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it simpler:

```
NAMESPACE.table = $('#assets-table').DataTable({
  "data": filteredData,
  "columns": [
      { "data": "id" },
      { "data": "type" },
      { "data": "city" },
      { "data": "state"}
  ],
 "destroy": true
 });
```

Comment: Nice, that is cleaner.

Comment: Great Solution!!

Answer (score 6):

if you want to clear the data present in dataTable simply call `table.clear()` it clears all cells in table.

and then add new data using `table.row.add().draw()`;

`table.destroy()` does not removes data present in cell of table, it only destroys the current instance of dataTable you created.

Comment: It seems so inefficient to do that, clearing everything when you just want to add a row any way. The problem is I want the user to remove items, then probably this is the only way, since there is no `table.row.remove` API which is a bit weird to me? But I just needed somebody to say this is the only way.. so here we go. Thanks +1